# MySQL query Where x = Anything

Tags: php, mysql

i'm currently creating a list of radio buttons that will filter down my data base at the moment the query im using is

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Activities = '{$activities}' AND Climate = '{$climate}' AND Continent = '{$continent}
```

My problem is the end query "Continent" has a list of continents to pick from but also an "Any" radio button. This is causing an error as i can't think of what value i need to attach to the raido button in order for it to just select everything.

Thanks,

Comment: Just make an option called "any". If that is chosen omit that portion of your wehre clause. That's it.

Comment: The current radip button for any is:    <input type="radio" name="continent" <?php if (isset($continent) && $continent=="any") echo "checked";?>  value=''>Any

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LIKE clause, and set any to %.  This will pull from any continent stored on the table.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Activities = '{$activities}' AND Climate = '{$climate}' AND Continent LIKE '{$continent}
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html